# more character when reading from file

Tags: c, string, list, file, output

I didn't found anything else related to my problem..so here we are.
Straight to the point, I'm using Manjaro x64 and I created a plain text file, this file is input for a file .c following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STRING 50

struct lista
{
    char data;
    struct lista *next;
};
typedef struct lista Nodo;

void read_file(FILE *fp, char *stringa);
Nodo * create_list(char *s);
void print_list(Nodo *lis);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc <= 1)
    {
        printf("Error: Not enough parameters\n");
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Nodo *lis = NULL;

    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error, failed when opening file, does it exist?\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char str[MAX_STRING];
    read_file(fp, str);
    fclose(fp);
    lis = create_list(str);
    print_list(lis);
    printf("\n\n");

    free(lis);
}

void read_file(FILE *fp, char *stringa)
{
    unsigned int i=0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(ch != '\0')
        {
            *(stringa + i) = ch;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

Nodo * create_list(char *s)
{
    Nodo *headPtr;

    if (*s=='\0')
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        headPtr = (Nodo *) malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
        if (headPtr==NULL)
            return NULL;

        headPtr->data = *s;
        headPtr->next = create_list(s+1);
        return headPtr;
    }
}

void print_list(Nodo *lis)
{
    if(lis == NULL)
        return;
    else
    {
        printf("%c", lis->data);
        print_list(lis->next);
    }
}
```

the .txt file:

```
Hello World!
How are you?
```

Now, using gcc it says me there are no error, and everything is fine, but something is wrong with the .txt file which add some more character...as it shown in the output below:

```
[pasquale@pasquale-Manjaro Desktop]$ ./a.out file.txt 
Hello World!
How are you?
11V

[pasquale@pasquale-Manjaro Desktop]$
```

Why it adds '11V' (every time I execute it change)? I thought it was .txt file fault and tried to edit from command prompt using 'nano' or 'vi'(reading) but nothing changed, tried to edit code changing something but nothing...
Then I also noticed that: if my file is longer program abort execution and the end of printing the list

```
Hello World!
How are you?
Hello World!
How are you?
Hello World!
How are you?
Hello World!
How are you?
```

How can I fix all of these strange output?

Comment: Your `read_file` function should add the terminating `NUL` character at the end of a string.

Comment: It doesn't change nothing, it continues add some random character at the end of the string when reading from file

Comment: `"Error, failed when opening file, does it exist?\n"` is a useless error message.  Don't ask the user a question, tell the user why `fopen` failed: `perror(argv[1]);`

Comment: `fgetc` returns an int.  `while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF )` is incorrect when `c` is of type `char`.

Answer (score 0):

`str` has no null terminator, so, you should add `*(stringa + i) = '\0';` after

```
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    if(ch != '\0')
    {
        *(stringa + i) = ch;
        i++;
    }
}
```

You also said your program aborts execution in case of longer file, it's because `MAX_STRING` (length of `str`) is 50, increase the value of `MAX_STRING` in case of larger files or dynamically allocate `str`

Answer (score 0):

The primary issues you have are the failure to append the null terminator to the string, and overflowing the buffer.   `create_list` is relying on the existence of the null terminator, but you do not write the null terminator to the string so your list is being constructed incorrectly.  (In fact, the program is exhibiting undefined behavior either when it tries to read from an uninitialized member of the array, or when it writes beyond the bounds of the array.)  Avoid both problems by building the list while you read the data instead of trying to read the file into a fixed sized buffer :

```
#include<stdio.h>                                                                  
#include<stdlib.h>                                                                 
                                                                                   
struct lista {                                                                     
        char data;                                                                 
        struct lista *next;                                                        
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
struct lista * read_file(FILE *);                                                  
struct lista * create_list(char);                                                  
void print_list(struct lista *);                                                   
void free_list(struct lista *);                                                    
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                       
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;                         
        struct lista *lis;                                                         
        if( fp == NULL ){                                                          
                perror(argv[1]);                                                   
                return 1;                                                          
        }                                                                          
        lis = read_file(fp);                                                       
        fclose(fp);                                                                
        print_list(lis);                                                           
        free_list(lis);
        return 0;                                                           
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
struct lista *                                                                     
read_file(FILE *fp)                                                                
{                                                                                  
        int ch;   /* Not a char! fgetc returns int */                                                                 
        struct lista *head = NULL;                                                 
        struct lista **tail = &head;                                               
        while( (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ){                                          
                *tail = create_list(ch);                                           
                tail = &((*tail)->next);                                           
        }                                                                          
        return head;                                                               
}
                                                                              
struct lista *                                                                     
create_list(char s)                                                                
{                                                                                  
        struct lista *headPtr = malloc(sizeof *headPtr);                           
        if( headPtr == NULL ){                                                     
                perror("malloc");                                                  
                exit(1);                                                           
        }                                                                          
        headPtr->data = s;                                                         
        headPtr->next = NULL;                                                      
        return headPtr;                                                            
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void                                                                               
print_list(struct lista *lis)                                                      
{                                                                                  
        if( lis != NULL ){                                                         
                putchar(lis->data);                                                
                print_list(lis->next);                                             
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void                                                                               
free_list(struct lista *lis)                                                       
{                                                                                  
        if( lis != NULL ){                                                         
                struct lista *n = lis->next;                                       
                free(lis);                                                         
                free_list(n);                                                      
        }                                                                          
}
```